# Prevent HTML page indexing by search engines

Tags: html, seo

In my website i have a page where i put just some "Text datas" and i use it as an simple database.
to be more clear it's a Quotes with their author name (i.e. :

```
<div id="QUO12012022">
    <h1>Author NAME</h1>
    <span>QUOTE TEXT</span> 
</div>
```

an so on, and in my mainpage a script load each day the quote and display it in the main page.
While testing and searching google directly with my website name, it loaded in the result a direct link to this data page,
My question obviously is how to make this page just invisible to search engine and still be able to load data from it in my internal script, ?

PS : since it's simple exercice and as i am still beginner, i don't want to use sql database, just simple text stuff like this.

Thanks.

Comment: It's doable but we need more info on your website, are you using a CMS? did you use PHP ? Javascript ?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.  Please also include the details requested in the previous comment when you ask there so that it isn't closed because it needs more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent most search engine web crawlers from indexing a page on your site, place the following meta tag into the  section of your page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

To prevent only Google web crawlers from indexing a page:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

Comment: Thanks, that what i was searching page at once, i am having a reading here https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag?hl=fr